# How to disable button and then enable it after textbox.textchanged event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a user control which acts as a form for updating student records. This user control is used in a page called students update. After the update is sucessfull, I want to disable the update button. After that, if the user changes any text, the update button should be enabled back. I am trying this but it is not working. I have all my textboxes autopost property to true. I am able to disable, but I am not able to enable it again if user starts entering new text in the text box. I am using the textbox.textchanged event to achieve this.

Comment: You have to use client-side java scripting (or jQuery) to achieve this goal.

Comment: @AlexBell May I ask you why can't I do it serve side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Jquery approach :

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" Enabled="false" />
    </div>
    </form>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>").keyup(function () {
                $("#<%= Button1.ClientID %>").attr("disabled", $(this).val() == "");
        });
    </script>


</body>
```

Or you can do this server-side :

```
<asp:textbox id="TextBox1" runat="server" autopostback="True" ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:textbox>
<asp:button id="Button1" runat="server" enabled="False" text="Button" />

protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button1.Enabled = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a way I could do this server side?

Comment: Thanks client side works better than server side. So, I might stick with jquery. What is the "$(this).val() == "")" doing in your code? Your code works great. I am just trying to understand it. Thanks!

Comment: $(this).val() == "" is a conditional expression, it will return boolean type, "true" or "false" according to the textbox value. The attr function is for setting attribute for elements, you can read more here : http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-value

Comment: It means that the button is enabled (in other words, disabled=false; it's a typical syntax of jQuery)

Comment: @hoangnnm Why not just directly set it true and false? I apologize, this is the first time I'm using jquery.

Comment: because this way is faster, normally if you want to set it to true or false , you will have to : *begin* if textbox.value = "" then textbox.enabled = false else textbox.enabled = true *end* , you see what am i talking about ?

Answer (score 1):

@Hoangnnm solution looks OK. Just include the later jQuery Lib, e.g. version 1.9.0 instead of 1.4.1 which is quite obsolete:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```